# How to get URL Line?

Tags: html, line

On click my icon and go to my Line profile.

```
<a href="URL Line profile">http://www.test12345679/lineicon.jpg</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the url in href attribute like
`href="http://google.com"`

Comment: You mean to say dynamic url

Comment: @NurmpungUnchalee will you plz describe briefly. so we can understood.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to have an image or icon that links to your profile.

```
<a href="URL Line profile">
  <img alt="icon" src="http://www.test12345679/lineicon.jpg">
</a>
```